# Linking test automation code with written test cases without cucumber/gherkin

Tags: java, selenium, testing, agile, erp

To automate the functional testing of my company's project (which is a custom ERP software developed in agile/scrum), we previously used Squash TM and its integration with Cucumber to keep track of requirements being tested/automated.

However, due to the scale of the project and the limitations of BDD/Gherkin, we adopted data driven testing using JUnit 5 by feeding different configurations and input to selenium via excel data sets. So far it has been successful, but we lost the traceability provided by the squash/cucumber workflow since the project is no longer following BDD methodology.

Are there any tools or frameworks we can use to link our test code with tests written by our test lead? Particularly, linking the non-gherkin Squash classic test cases with out JUnit5-based Selenium tests, or any viable alternatives other than Cucumber/Gherkin.

Comment: Questions asking for recommendations for libraries, frameworks, etc. are off-topic for Stack Overflow, sorry

Answer (score 1):

It's the old school approach which can be adopted here..Each test case/ scenario should be named By their Method name. Say your Testcases are Creating Facebook account, Adding Friends, Joining group, E2E For Creating FBaccount and adding friend. You create methods (equivalent to Step Definition) and use those methods' names in the Excel sheet. Now to replace tag, either you can write a utility method to check in excel in tag column next to Testcase method name column, what ever tag you want to execute present or not. in This way your testcase would be linked without Gherkin and Cucumber. BTW  Gherkin is free.

Comment: Gherkin proved to be a bit of an obstacle because the project's features end up needing gigantic data sets which make the feature unreadable and harder to troubleshoot when using the examples table in scenario outlines. Using excel for those data sets also clashed with gherkin due to loops forcing us to do actions and assertions in the same step.
Your suggestion sounds like it could solve the problem, but our test cases are provided through Squash TM and not excel, so we can't check the tags/method names as easily.

Comment: You may need to figure out if Squash TM has a Plugin for Selenium. If yes the You can read the steps and Through String Operation Find Keywords (eg. Login to Application) which would be the same as your method name and if it matches the method name it would execute that method. The only challenge here is to find if Squash TM as any plugin using using you can access the tool through Selenium.